# System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid Only on certain Machines

Tags: c#, .net

We have code that casts an object to a short.

```
type.BusinessAreaID = (short)caType.credit_assessment_biz_areaReference.EntityKey.EntityKeyValues[0].Value;
```

The object has the value of 2.

This code (unit test) works on the PC of the developer that created the code. But we get a invalid cast exception on the build server and on another dev PC.

The BusinessAreaID is of type short.

The Dll is also in the GAC, we have updated that so that it should be the same.

Anyone have any ideas.

Comment: Work from the assumption that the object doesn't have the value 2 on the machines that throw the exception.

Comment: It is run from a unit test so the value is always 2, have also debugged to make sure

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't unbox a value to a different type. For example, this works:

```
short x = 2;
object y = (object)x;
short z = (short)y;
```

but this does not:

```
int x = 2;
object y = (object)x;
short z = (short)y; // InvalidCastException
```

Are you sure the value stored in `caType...lues[0].Value` is of type `short`?

Comment: That's the type of the property. But as you can see in my example, you can store a value of type `short` in a variable of type `object`.